# Different server of subdomain(HostMonster) & domain (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-route53

So I have these 2 different endpoints

1. blog.subdomain.com - The wordpress files of this located on my hosting `(HostMonster)`
2. domain.com - This was a parked domain, but recently tried to use `AWS` to upload my files and point this `domain.com` A Record & Nameserver to `AWS`.

`blog.subdomain.com` was working fine before, but not until when I tried to point my `domain.com` to my `AWS Ec2 Instance`. The changes I made was changing the a record of my `domain.com` pointed to aws `public ip`and changed the nameserver into `aws`

I'm using `Loadbalancer & Route53` on my `domain.com`.

Now I wonder how can I keep the blog.domain.com files uploaded to my hosting at the same time the domain.com files are uploaded to `aws ec2 instance?` The showing on my blog.subdomain.com is `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

[image]

Just want to know some possible ways to fix this, without transferring the files again and again.

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create the `blog` CNAME or A record in AWS Route53 pointing back to the original webserver (hostmonster) as Route53 is now acting as your nameserver.

Clients will no longer query the old nameservers that you used before, hence you have to have all the records in AWS.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hello, can I have document for this situation or any step by step procedure?

Comment: @RaeIan 1. Login to your previous dns service (e.g. godaddy or whatever you used), 2. list the zone in question (example.com), 3. note all the records (e.g. blog.example.com) except SOA and NS records, 4. create the same ones in AWS R53.

Comment: Does this means I need to create another record set for blog.subdomain.com like in the updated picture above?

Comment: @RaeIan Yes. If you want `blog.domain.com` resolved you must have a record for `blog` in `domain.com` zone, quite obviously.

Comment: I saw the list of records, is this the things I need to add on my R53? CNAME, MX (Mail Exchanger), TXT (Text), SRV (Service)?

Comment: @RaeIan All but NS and SOA.

Comment: @RaeIan Look - you’ve had some records in the old server. Now you switched to a new server (Route53) and the old one is no longer used. Obviously you need to recreate *all the records* from the old server in R53, otherwise they won’t resolve because they’re not there. It’s not a rocket science.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108471/discussion-between-rae-ian-and-mlu).